# Set a custom Attached Property with a XAML Setter

Tags: wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I wanted to set a custom **Attached Property** that I attached to my Textboxes.

My name space is correctly imported, and used for other things in my UserControl so it works fine.

I can't seem to find the correct syntax for this.

Here is what I currently have (I tried to add brackets at different places, but it doesn't work) :

```
... 
  <DataTrigger ...>
    <Setter ... />
    <Setter Property="(MyCustomXMLNS:TextBoxExtend).MyProperty" Value="..." />
  </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

This is only a syntax problem here, do you guys know how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use parentheses in a Setter for an attached property, so the correct syntax is

```
<Setter Property="MyCustomXMLNS:TextBoxExtend.MyProperty" Value="..."/>
```

You would use parentheses when the property is the source of a Binding, like

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(MyCustomXMLNS:TextBoxExtend.MyProperty)}"
             Value="...">
```